# Haunted Woods YA book from the 80s or 90s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

The details I remember are very hazy.

What I remember is that it was a young adult horror novel from the late 80s / early 90s.

Two kids live in a town, and the town has a section where the woods are haunted and very bad things happen if you go into them.  There is a lot of snow in the book and the cover of the edition I remember had snow on it as well.

At one point in the book, they sneak out and go into the haunted woods at night.

That's about what I got.  I don't remember why they do anything or what happens, but I remember reading it at least twice and liking it.

Any help?

**Update** - [*a bit more info*]:

I know it is not from the Goosebumps series - the content was for slightly older kids.  It is possible that it is from the Fear Street series or some other RL Stine, but I looked through the titles and plot summaries and none of them seem to fit.  I'm fairly certain it wasn't Christopher Pike, and until searching for this, I have no memory of ever hearing of the *Point Horror* series.  I don't think it was actually part of a series at all, but I wouldn't stake more than a nickel on that.

Also; I hesitate to put this, because I think it is likely a corrupted memory, and may make things harder; but in the absence of any quick answers, I'll give it a shot.  I think the title was something like *Night(mares | time ) in Ghostland*

That could be way off base, but for some reason, that title strikes a chord in memory.  I hope the extra info helps.

Comment: Do you remember if it was part of a franchise?  Like Point Horror, Goosebumps, etc.?

Comment: @ssav - See my update to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the update, I think this is [Nights In Ghostland](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2107159.Nights_in_Ghostland) by Carol Beach York.

> What I remember is that it was a young adult horror novel from the late 80s / early 90s.

Published 1987 so fits the dates.

> Two kids live in a town, and the town has a section where the woods are haunted and very bad things happen if you go into them. There is a lot of snow in the book and the cover of the edition I remember had snow on it as well.

The cover shown on the GoodReads page shows two children in a snowy woodland (with some ghostly-looking skeletons).  Obviously the title is a pretty close match.

I can't find anything about the plot except one line from [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Nights_in_Ghostland.html?id=O9QCf6Y4cyIC&redir_esc=y): *Laura and her brother Douglas must help the ghost of their Uncle Jack return the money he stole from a hunchback, himself a restless ghost, so that both spirits can rest in peace*

Comment: That's the one!  Good find!  I searched Google repeatedly, but my queries must've off by just enough.  Also, based on new searches, it appears that there is only one image of the cover I was looking for online, and you found it.  That is awesome.  Thanks again!